# What does the greater than symbol do on the left side of a ternary operator in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, ternary-operator

I came across a new syntax for a ternary operation in PHP.

```
$this->view->totalNumber > $itemsPerPage ? $this->view->renderPaginator = true 
                                         : $this->view->renderPaginator = false;
```

Is this some sort of short-hand for only apply the ternary operation if the resulting value is greater than the existing value for the left side variable?

Comment: no, it's the condition.  literally, "if totalNumber is greater than itemsPerPage".

Comment: The person who has written that should be... I would call that short hand idiot operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just the comparison operation. You can rewrite it like this if it helps you understand:

```
($this->view->totalNumber > $itemsPerPage) ? $this->view->renderPaginator = true : $this->view->renderPaginator = false;
```

Now a better way to write it would be simply to do:

```
$this->view->renderPaginator = ($this->view->totalNumber > $itemsPerPage);
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. its a much much nicer way than the first example.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->view->renderPaginator = $this->view->totalNumber > $itemsPerPage;
```

Really , people. You all should be ashamed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all that code is doing is evaluating the expression

```
$this->view->totalNumber > $itemsPerPage
```

which resolves to a boolean true or false, which is then checked by the ternary operator.

Enclosing it in parentheses would make it more clear:

```
($this->view->totalNumber > $itemsPerPage) ? $this->view->renderPaginator = true : $this->view->renderPaginator = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorthand if statement. A more complex version of

```
($a > $b) ? "execute here if a is greater than b" : "here if not";
```

So the greater than symbol™ works just as a comparison operator.